# How can I reset a diverged branch back to master

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Is it possible to reset a remote branch to another remote branch?

Let's say I have two branches: `master` and `develop`. The `develop` branch is made from `master` and used as an *integration/build* branch. It serves no other purpose.

At the end of a sprint all feature branches, which are approved, are merged into master.

At the end of the sprint, everyone is required to delete his local copy of the develop branch, we delete the remote one, and a new one is made from master. This is not ideal, but the strategy we use itself is the one we agreed upon and bests suits or needs. It's loosely based on the branch-per-feature strategy.

The problem is that, if someone doesn't delete his local copy, and performs an update, he gets the message that his local develop branch is ahead of the remote one. This is because feature branches which were merged in from the previous sprint but did not make it into master are still on his local copy. The build infrastructure itself is also at risk, because if we don't perform a fully clean checkout we risk old stuff still being present.

Actions like `reset --hard` don't work, they might reset my local copy, but I'm not able to push these through to the remote branch.

Is there a way to make the develop branch completely identical to the master branch using commits, rather than recreating it?

Comment: How about `git reset --hard origin/master` ?

Comment: That doesn't work because I'm not able to push that reset to the remote. If I reset, my local copy is indeed clean, but the remote isn't.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you might want to take a look at Git-Flow, which uses develop/master/feature branches, but avoids the problem you're seeing: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ and  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, your branches are `master` and `develop`.  You want to reset `develop` back to `master`:

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard master
git push -f <remote> develop
```

Or, if you've already deleted the local branch `develop`, you can do it in one step:

```
git push -f <remote> master:develop
```

This pushes the local branch `master`, but names it `develop` on the remote.

The `-f` or `--force` flag means "Yes, Git, I'm trying to delete data.  I know what I'm doing."  In this case, pushing `develop` would lose the remote commits, but you use `-f` to tell Git that you want to lose those commits.  Never use `-f` unless you know why.

Comment: If I force push, does this mean the other developers will get a "reset" if they pull? Or do they still have all their commits on develop present?

Comment: They will have to `reset` when they pull, if they have local copies of `develop`.  So, yes, they will still have all of their commits on `develop` present.  Git is really trying to help you out here by making it harder for you to accidentally lose data; in this particular case you *do* want to lose data so Git makes you jump through one extra hoop.

Comment: Is there a way that they can 'revert' or 'pull' my force push and lose their local changes? (That's the intent, I want their local copy to reflect remote, without them having to delete their local copy of the branch.)

Comment: @Jensen: Git is just trying to help you by protecting your data from deletion.  Git's promise to you is that whenever you run `git pull`, you won't lose any data.  That's the whole point of Git: its entire purpose is to record your data and protect it from getting accidentally deleted.  But that's not what *you* want in this particular case.  So, if you actually want Git to delete your data, you have to explicitly say so.  This is why everyone pulling will need to delete their branches first with `git branch -D` or reset the branches afterwards with `git reset`.

Answer (score 1):

Update your local version to the commit you want and then force push it to your remote repository:

```
git fetch origin
git branch -f develop origin/master
git push origin develop --force
```