# Messed up with my local git branch. how do i revert back to cleanly working master branch

Tags: git, github

My git **Master branch** is working clean without problems and i "git push master" it, Then i created a new branch called **development** and i messed up in this branch in my local machine.

i didn't do any commit or push yet.

1. can i check out to my master branch and simply delete the development branch. if i do what happen to local changes i did to my program in that development branch.
2. or i do commit the development branch and delete it before merging with master, and the i made a pull request.

need suggestions.... plz help...

Comment: Do you want to keep any of your (not yet committed) changes?

Comment: This thread helped me with a similar issue: [Reset Diverged branch back to master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671124/how-can-i-reset-a-diverged-branch-back-to-master)

Comment: i don't want to keep any changes in development branch. i want all codes to be same as in master branch

Comment: If you haven't commited anything yet, then the dev branch head is still the same as master; your question appears to be "how do I revert some, but not all, of the changes in my working copy??"

Comment: @chepner . my question is , how to revery back all the changes i did my development branch to same as in master branch(freshly created development branch) ?  although i didn't do any commits in development branch .

Comment: Then you haven't messed up the *branch* at all; you just have changes to the working copy you want to discard. @mbuechmann's answer covers that.

Comment: @chepner thank u for the reply

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset local changes you can just do

```
git checkout -- .
```

This will delete all changes of all tracked files. If you have new files, you can just delete them with `rm`.

Now the branches development and master will point to the same ref.

Comment: if i "get checkout -- ." all the changes i do locally in the development branch will get reverted to same as master branch?

Comment: @AshokKumar They will revert to the state of the last commit on `development` branch. If you indeed created `development` after `master` branch AND you never committed, it will then be the same as `master`.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @AshokKumar You could also have commited whatever changes you had, then dropped the branch altogether to recreate it.

Comment: Not just "now"; `development` and `master` *always* pointed to the same ref, because `development` hasn't been advanced by any commits yet.

Comment: @RomainValeri .  **drop the branch** means just delete the branch(-d) , rite?. this also will revert changes back to same as **master** branch?

Answer (score 0):

mbuechmann's answer is working fine, but just to state here what's been hinted at in comments, there is indeed another way of dealing with this situation, with the slight benefit of giving you the opportunity to look at these unwanted changes later if need arises :

```
# let's commit all local changes on development branch
git commit -am "broken : bug X occurred in part Y"

# you can't delete a currently checked out branch so let's go to master
git checkout master

# (optional) want to keep a copy of these unwanted changes, "just in case" ?
git branch broken_dev_181219 development

# then delete and recreate development anew
git branch -D development
git checkout -b development
```